# URL rewrites not working and keep changing the URL extension

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I cannot get the URL rewrite in Magento to work correctly at all. I'm trying to redirect a category to a CMS page and at first try it works fine. After I refresh, it starts to change the URL extensions to something completely different than what's shown for the category URL. I've tried clearing the cache and reindexing the URL rewrite but that seems to change it again!

And if I do try to change the URL rewrite to this new, random, made up one that's being automatically inputted - it changes it again! I'm so confused here..

Answer (score 0):

Fixing weird URL Rewrites

Sometimes when you make changes to your products, or enable a certain extension, Magento might start to rewrite all your URLs to include a suffix "-1" or some other number. Within the URL Rewrites, Magento differentiates between System URLs and Custom URLs. If the System URLs are broken like this, you should not fix this by adding new Custom URLs.

Instead, open up phpMyAdmin, create a backup of your Magento database, and flush the Magento table `core_url_rewrite` (so that it becomes totally empty). Immediately afterwards, refresh the Catalog Url Rewrites under Index Management. This will regenerate all System URLs.

You can  also try to redirect through the `.htaccess.`
Redirect 301 /site-URL-to-redirect www.site.com/url-destination

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to redirect your category page to cms.

1. Using Magento native URL rewrite managment. 
   In Magento 1.x go to

`admin -> catalog -> url rewrite managment -> add new url`

select custom in Create URL Rewrite: drop down and then give your categoy url as request and cms page as target.

2. Using `.htaccess` file. Add this line of code into the file .htaccess:

`Redirect category-url  cms-page-url`